# Sending phone a notification when a .NET software notifies me on PC

Tags: .net, push-notification

so my part-time job uses this clunky PC software (I could tell that it's .NET by looking at the files but idk anything else about it). It notifies the PC in real time when there's a task request that I have to complete, but I wish there was a way for it notify me on my iphone as well. Is there a simple tool / script that I can write to automate this? Or am I out of luck by not having access to the codebase of the software.

Since the software is written in .NET, I was hoping there's some way to access notification requests by the software. Googling didn't really help so I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: see also https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject your own code to mostly any program.
On Windows with i.e. [CreateRemoteThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) or DLL sideloading.

With .NET it's just easier, cause there is no need to reverse low level assembly to find the right place to inject. NET IL is quite high level and with help of [decompiler](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy.) can be reverted to mostly original source code.

And you can use [Harmony](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony) for easier injection into managed runtime. Or apply static patch with [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil).

If you are not familiar with general purpose programming you can try some luck with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Tutorial.htm) (AutoIt) and it's [ControlGetText](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/ControlGetText.htm).